# entity-framework get entityreference value

Tags: entity-framework

I have an entity object which is connected to another entities.

I want to loop through all entity properties , if the property is String then do something with the value.
If the property is `EntityReference`, I want to get it's value (it has only one), and do something with the value as well.

I was able to determine if the property is string or EntityReference. 
I get the String value by -

```
value = typeof(entity).GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(request, null);
```

but how do I get the value of an `entityreference` ?

Comment: I guess by `If the property is EntityReference` you mean if it is any other related entity?

Answer (score 0):

Just trace the property tree.
You have the first step. repeat for lower properties.

```
var    TopLevelProp = poco.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(poco, null);
var    LowerProp    =  TopLevelProp.GetType().GetProperty("aLowerPropName").GetValue(TopLevelProp, null);
```

although you tagged this EF.   What did you mean by entity reference ?

**edit:  in the hope i have covered the  entity and its key question**
Here is a sample Repository covering EF Context and entity access.  See the Entity field and **Entity KEY field methods**...

```
 public class Repository<T> : IRepositoryEF<T> where T : BaseObject {
    public RepositoryEF(DbContext context) { Context = context; }

    public DbEntityEntry<T> Entry(T entity) { return Context.Entry(entity); }
    public DbSet<T> EntityDbSet() { return Context.Set<T>(); } 
    public ObjectContext ObjectContext { get { return ((IObjectContextAdapter) this.Context).ObjectContext; } }

    public DbContext Context { get; protected set; }

    public EntityState GetEntityState(object entity) { return Context.Entry(entity).State; }

    public  ObjectSet<T> GetObjectSet() { return ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>(); }

    public IList<string> GetEntityFields() {
        var entityFields = GetObjectSet().EntitySet.ElementType.Properties;
        return entityFields.Select(e => e.Name).ToList();
    }
    public string[] GetEntityKeyFields() { return GetObjectSet().EntitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers.Select(k => k.Name).ToArray(); }

    public EntityKey GetEntityKey(T entity) {
        if (entity == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return ObjectContext.CreateEntityKey(GetObjectSet().EntitySet.Name, entity);
    }


    public string GetEntityKeyAsString(T entity) {
        if (entity == null) {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        var eK = GetEntityKey(entity);
        var keyAsString = eK.EntityKeyValues.Aggregate("", (current, keyField) => current + keyField.Key + "=" + keyField.Value + ",");
        return keyAsString;
    }
}
```

**If you want to get all the metadata in the Context:**

```
ObjectContext objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
        MetadataWorkspace workspace = objContext.MetadataWorkspace;
        IEnumerable<EntityType> managedTypes = workspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace);
```

You can go to town on the meta data. see all enums values in DataSpace to get at various parts of the model

Comment: Hi, It doesn't work. In my entity i have several foreign keys. I want to loop through all the foreign keys (properties) in the entity and get their values (from different tables - where the primary key is). How can i do it ?

Comment: then you combine loop at Data value and loop and looping properties

Comment: can you write an example? i don't understand what type of property i need to loop thorough

Comment: can you describe the sample problem? all you asked for was `but how do I get the value of an entityreference ?`

Comment: What type of entity property do i need to loop through in order to get the value of the foreign key?

Comment: Its a bit hard to follow the line of questioning. Its like you are trying to discover your model from the context.   EF works best if you use Generics where T is known. And patterns are used. EG all objects have key called Id.   BUT if you really do have a model discovery problem then the meta work space and entity methods in edit can get at all possible info.